# golang converting time.Time to unix adds extra hours

Tags: go, time, timestamp

I ran into a problem.
The PostgreSQL database stores the date and time in the format "timestamp without time zone".
If you get the date and time from the database and try to convert it to seconds it adds 4 extra hours
Example:

```
fmt.Println(menu.OpeningRecordAt, "|", time.Unix(menu.OpeningRecordAt.Unix(), 0))
// 2023-05-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC | 2023-05-21 04:00:00 +0400 +04
```

What are some ways to fix this or convert the date and time seconds more correctly?

I tried changing the data type in postgres to timestamp with time zone but the conversion also adds extra hours

Comment: Looks like timezone problem. Use `t.In(time.UTC)`

Comment: @BurakSerdar, I tried it but it didn't work, or maybe I'm doing something wrong:

menu.OpeningRecordAt,  time.Unix(menu.OpeningRecordAt.In(time.UTC).Unix(), 0),  menu.OpeningRecordAt.In(time.UTC).Unix()

ans:
2023-05-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC | 2023-05-21 04:00:00 +0400 +04 | 1684627200

Answer (score 3):

The documentation:

> [Package time](https://pkg.go.dev/time@latest)
>
> ```
> func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
> ```
>
> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

As expected, you got your local time: `2023-05-21 04:00:00 +0400`. You want UTC time.

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    at, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2023-05-21")
    fmt.Println(at, err)
    // got
    local := time.Unix(at.Unix(), 0)
    fmt.Println(local)
    // want
    utc := time.Unix(at.Unix(), 0).UTC()
    fmt.Println(utc)
}
```

Local US Eastern Daylight Saving Time (EDT):

```
2023-05-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>
2023-05-20 20:00:00 -0400 EDT
2023-05-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: this does work, but in context it is a piece of code for one of the grpc services that returns a structure with timestamp. And I would like to pass the right timestamp at once so I don't have to bring it to utc in other grpc services that use it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem this way

```
tm := time.Date(
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Year(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Month(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Day(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Hour(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Minute(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Second(),
    menu.OpeningRecordAt.Nanosecond(),
    time.Local,
)
```

is there a better option?